# how to convert ascii to byte array format

Tags: android, native

i want to convert the ascii code to byte array format:

**Code :**

```
byte[] byteArr = passenger_sign.getBytes();
```

**Output :**

```
[B@34c59da
```

i dont know how to convert it to byte array format,anyone have solution for this.

Comment: i get the length for this data---->[91,66,64,56,55,57,56,57,102,57]
length---->32

Comment: it get the position of the json object in the json array.

Comment: Any how thank you for your kind reply...brother

Answer (score 0):

Refer this link 
[https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/lang/string/convert-string-to-byte-array-ascii-encoding/]

```
public static byte[] stringToBytesASCII(String str) {
 byte[] b = new byte[str.length()];
 for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
  b[i] = (byte) str.charAt(i);
 }
 return b;
}
```